# Why Workflow fire when object upserted

Tags: workflow, upsert

I create a workflow which will send an email only when a user created.
But when i upsert users, it send emails to all user.
What upsert do is delete and insert again ??? and can i change workflow to avoid that?

Answer (score 0):

Actually upsert means Update and Insert .
So according to the criteria rule done in workflow it will trigger the workflow if the condition is true.

There are three options to choose while you create workflow as shown in the below screen shot.
[image]

You should select created radio button if you want to send a mail when a user is created.
During upsert only users that are inserted will get a mail.